# Does a "normal" lithium battery BMS limit the current going into the battery when charging?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, lithium, bms

If I hook up a 42 V voltage source with an absurd peak amperage to a 42 V battery through a BMS, will it protect the battery from too much current?

Comment: Yes, but only by tripping, not limiting it. That assumes a real BMS with its own MOSFET(s). There are signaling only BMSes which only tells the charger or consumer to stop.

Comment: I’m not voting to close this question because it didn't need it.

Comment: @ocrdu's answer is an excellent summary of what to expect. A BMS is a protection system, not a charge controller. Some people rely on a BMS in lieu of a charger - which is extremely unwise.

Answer (score 5):

There are many types of BMS (and many definitions of "normal"), but generally, in case of too high a charging current, a BMS will not limit the current to an acceptable level but simply stop the charging, and yes, this does protect the battery, but there will be no charging.

Some BMSes will reset after a while and "try again"; most will have to be reset by removing the power source.

BMSes are for last-ditch over/undervoltage and overcurrent protection when something goes wrong with charging or discharging your battery pack; they don't implement (a part of) a proper lithium battery charging algorithm (like a dedicated charger does).